# What's the best way to migrate SELECT applications and data from an old Mac to a new one?

Tags: macos, mac, migration

I know I can make an easy transfer of **everything** using time machine, but I'm trying to transfer the minimum necessary to the new computer (applications I currently use, Aperture database, etc.) in order to keep the new machine as clean as possible, and avoid starting out with any legacy problems with permissions, etc.

Clearly, I can copy individual apps and databases to an external drive and then install them on the new machine, but I'm trying to find an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the ideas.  I would have voted the response up if I had enough points, even though it wasn't quite right for my needs:  I ran into the thing KeithB pointed out - I didn't want to transfer things wholesale.  Here's what I did - bunch of steps, but pretty painless, and faster than I thought it would be.

I got my new Macbook last night, linked it to my old one with ethernet, and just used file sharing over that mini-network to copy my data and libraries.  My goal was to install fresh versions everything  possible. It's all pretty obvious, but I was impressed with how easy it was to get all my data over with almost no "legacy" items that might someday be a corrupting influence on my young MBP.

- First, I had time machine run a
  backup on the old machine, just in case
- I turned off airport on both machines
  and connected the ethernet cable to
  both.   (This is obvious to most, but
  don't use wifi unless you have very
  little data; it's MUCH slower.
- I enabled file sharing in the target
  machine, (System Prefs, Sharing) and
  set permissions to "Read and Write"
  for "Everyone".  (It's important to
  turn this off after you're done and
  will be going back to "real"
  networks, but it's harmless on the
  two-mac ethernet ecosystem)
- This allowed me to see the new
  computer in the left nav panel of the
  old one, and to drag files into it.
- On the new computer, I set address
  book and mail to sync with my google
  account (in their respective prefs
  panels)
- On the new computer, I set mobileme to sync my calendar,
  keychain, and browser bookmarks (In
  system prefs, then mobileme)
- On the old computer, I ran a repair of my aperture photo
  library just in case, (open aperture while holding option and command,)  and then
  copied the file and pasted it into the pictures folder
  on the new mac.
- I installed a clean copy of aperture
  using my existing license on the new
  machine, and pointed it to the
  library I'd just copied.
- I copied my entire itunes folder,
  found in the music folder of the old
  mac, to my new machine's desktop, and
  then dragged it into iphoto on the
  new machine, so it could "organize"
  the files fresh.  NOTE - this won't retain playlists or ratings.  If you use either much, you may want a more traditional migration for your itunes library.
- If you have any imovie projects, you
  can just drag the whole folder into
  the "Movies" folder on the new
  computer"
- I installed MS Office from the original disks on the new machine
- I copied the contents of my documents folder to the docs folder on the new machine.
- Just to be safe, I copied my entire
  user folder (the one that looks like
  a house) to my backup disk and to my
  idisk in case I need them later.  If
  you're storage space constrained,
  consider removing the photo library,
  imovie projects folder, and itunes
  folder, since you already copied them
  before you did this.
- I didn't have any apps that I still
  wanted that I couldn't download new,
  but if you did, you could obviously
  jsut drag them to the new
  Applications folder.  (I just
  downloaded new copies of handbrake,
  logmein, and things, and things
  synced with my iphone to get my data.)

Not sure this is the best way, but it was easy, took under two hours, and on the off-chance I find something I overlooked and need, I can always get it off time machine or the copies of my user folder on the backup drive or idisk.

All in, it took me about an hour of "doing" and about an hour to transfer the data (I moved about 125GB, mostly pictures and music.)

Hopefully this is of some use to anyone else looking for a highly selective transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at "Migration Assistant" in the Utilities directory (off Applications)? Note -- I haven't used it myself.

That utility should work over the network (so you don't need an external disk) and I think it gives you control over what gets transfered. It isn't whole disk but, like you want, user data and applications.

Note -- I tend to reinstall applications when moving to a new machine. Although a lot of applications for Mac OS X are self-contained (everything is in that application icon), there are some that install things in odd places on the hard drive and it can be a pain to track all those things down, or even to understand that something is missing (when all you get is a crash or weird error message).

Comment: Unfortunately, Migration Assistant cannot selectively transfer apps.  Its either all or nothing.  Its a feature I wish Apple would add.

Comment: The Migration Assistant allows SOME control over the transfer but does not allow selective Application transfer.

Use Appcleaner on the old machine to delete Apps you're not using and then use the Migration Assistant, it won't transfer apps if they're not there.

Migration Assistant instructions here:
http://macs.about.com/od/leopard105/ss/migratevol.htm

This is what you can control using Migration Assistant:

User Accounts, Applications, Network and Computer Settings, Files, and Volumes.